# While executing app.js it gives an error in console

Tags: node.js

```
var Random = require("random-js");
var random = new Random(Random.engines.mt19937().autoSeed());
var socketserver = require('https').Server(options, app);
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mt19937' of undefined
at Object. (/var/apps/app.js:22:40)
NodeJs Version v12.19.1

Comment: [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-js#mersenne-twister-api) it says you need to use `MersenneTwister19937.autoSeed()`. Are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: var random = new Random(Random.engines.mt19937().autoSeed());

Comment: I did it like that, without MersenneTwister19937

Comment: `const Random = require("random-js").Random;
const random = new Random(MersenneTwister19937.autoSeed());`
try it like this

Comment: const random = new Random(MersenneTwister19937.autoSeed());
                          ^

ReferenceError: MersenneTwister19937 is not defined

Comment: which version of `random-js` do you use?

Comment: random-js@2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of random-js your code should work, but in the latest version this should do the trick for you.

```
const {Random, MersenneTwister19937} = require("random-js");

const random = new Random(MersenneTwister19937.autoSeed());
const value = random.integer(1, 100);
```

The problem in the comments was that you need to require `MersenneTwister19937` as well as `Random`

Comment: Thank you so much :333